# Cloud database architecture for a location-based app

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm currently planning my database for my location-based Android app (vision for iOS app sometime in future).

I'm wondering if the following structure suits my needs. Quick rundown of what my app involves: finding a user within a 2km radius (geofence) and showing their profile (similar to matching with someone on Tinder).

So how I envision it is each user upload their `LatLon` location to my database via google maps API - and Android queries the database to find a user within the geofence.

PS: What is the best way to query users within a geofence?

My proposed database is [Google Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/) with the following document setup:

```
users: {
    2394824972439 (facebook_id): {
      gender: "male"
      currentLat: 37.234234,
      currentLon: 157.192835,
      profileImg1: googlecloudstorage.com/url/to/img1.png,
      profileImg2: googlecloudstorage.com/url/to/img2.png,
      bio: "This is my bio",
      alreadyMatchedWith: [42304823423, 23423423432, 023948230]
  }
    7388824972439: {
      gender: "female"
      currentLat: 34.234234,
      currentLon: 157.132835,
      profileImg1: googlecloudstorage.com/url/to/img1.png,
      profileImg2: googlecloudstorage.com/url/to/img2.png,
      bio: "Another bio",
      alreadyMatchedWith: [82304823423, 33423423432, 923948230]
  }
}
```

So the query will also ensure the other user's facebook ID (i'm using facebook for login) hasn't already been matched with. If it hasn't been matched with then the database will return the document of that user and display their profile info as well as profile images from google cloud. storage.

Are there any red flags about this setup I should be concerned about - or any better alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't mentioned GeoFire, and you pretend to do geo-related queries, GeoFire is probably the best alternative,

**GeoFire for Android/Java**

https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java

```
// creates a new query around [37.7832, -122.4056] with a radius of 2.0 kilometers
GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(37.7832, -122.4056), 2.0);
```

In the case you'll have to implement the same functionality for IOS:

**GeoFire for Objective-C**

https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc

Comment: Awesome - thanks. Here is the library that replicates GeoFire for Firestore: https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore I will try that

Comment: Cool. I wasn't aware the same geo functionality was already available for Firestore. Time to migrate the projects I have running on Firebase!